# ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("...").Activate generates Run-time error '-2147024809 (80070057)': The Item with the specified name wasn't found

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I have a macro to create a chart and modify its properties.

If I run the macro normally, I get

> Run-time error '-2147024809 (80070057)':
>   The Item with the specified name wasn't found.

[image]

on the last line of this code

```
Set ChtObj = Worksheets("summary").ChartObjects.Add(Left:=700, Top:=100, Width:=800, Height:=500)
With ChtObj
    .chart.ChartType = xlColumnStacked
    .chart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("statistics!A101:C" & targetRow)
    .Name = "waterfall"
End With
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("waterfall").Activate
```

If I run the code step by step, I get no errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write `Worksheets("summary").Activate` on the top of your code, it should work.

The problem is that during the macro running, your active sheet is not "summary". In general, using `Activesheet` is not a good practice in VBA - [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).